# Add intro text before profile 2 form in the registration page

Tags: 7, entities, users

I have a site that use profile 2 to add some field in the user registration page (/user) and via LoginToBoggan I can ask email x 2 and password x 2.

Now I need to insert a little introductive text before profile2 fields, like a phrase that explain why I need to ask that fields to the user.

How can I create it?

Comment: ZioBudda, I'm building a multi step form in d7, where I'm using the following modules:
- login toboggan
- profile2
- CAPTCHA It's causing a lot errors and don't seem to want to work together? Were you successful in getting this to work? If so, did you use a particular API module? Would it be possible to send sample code? Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup) module to display text. It is available as a field element.